# Android date pick field following guidelines

Tags: android

Following Android's design guidelines, I ran into this part https://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html, where they use a view that I believe is a `Spinner` in order to show and possibly select the date.

Please guide me in the right directions as I'm not 100% sure this is a `Spinner`, and also, checking the Calendar app, it seems once you click on it, a `DialogFragment` pops up, with a single `DatePicker` (or `TimePicker` for the hours), but I am not 100% sure of this either.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you need exactly ?

Comment: I need to know if I am correct by assuming guidelines suggests to use a `Spinner` view to select time and date, and also, how can I implement it, since spinner works with arrays to populate, I'm not sure how to **display** a date once its being picked.  Also I want to know If I'm correct by assuming the `Spinner` shows a `DialogFragment` once it's clicked

Comment: Look into datepicker, timepicker etc

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the docs, you can specify the Spinner mode.  Whether you choose to make it a dialog or dropdown is up to you.  Either way, you don't have to worry about setting the value after user has selected it.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#MODE_DIALOG

Comment: yeah, then what event triggers the dialog showing up. I need more info than that, the documentation doesn't show